# Why does socat UDP-RECVFROM terminate after exactly 1861 datagrams?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, limit, socat

Why does this terminate after exactly 1861 datagrams?

Host 2:

```
$ socat udp-recvfrom:12345,reuseaddr -
```

Host 1:

```
$ seq 1000000 | socat udp-sendto:host2:12345,reuseaddr -
```

On host 2, this prints out the lines:

```
0
1
...
1860
```

And then socat terminates with exit code 0, with no warning or error message.

I can't find any reference to this behaviour in the man page, or online. I can't find any reference to 1861 being some kind of special resource limit in Linux.

I'm using Linux kernel 5.16.7 (Arch) with socat-1.7.4.1.

EDIT: I think the problem here is my fundamental misunderstanding of what `socat udp-recvfrom` actually does. It only receives *one* datagram, and then terminates (as seen). So the issue is that the sender is combining a big chunk of `seq` output into a single datagram, which is then sent, and received as expected.

Therefore I think this question is resolved - thank you for your answers.

Comment: That looks like 1861 datagrams

Comment: @BenVoigt yes of course - edited.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does this terminate after exactly 1860 datagrams?

That's not what you see and that's likely not what happens either.
What you see is that the server side *receives* data up to 1860 and not more. Since UDP is an unreliable protocol it says nothing on how many datagrams where actually *sent* - and then got lost somewhere. Doing an `strace -e sendto` on socat shows that the data actually gets transmitted to the socket, so it is not that socat has stopped sending.

Since you send the data as fast as possible it is very likely that most of them got lost, but nobody cared (it's UDP!). For example if I run the same script on localhost the last data I get depending on the current mood or load on the system is between 20000 and 35000. Slowing down socat (by running it within `strace` and logging output) gives much more data since the receiver can better keep up with the sender.

`seq 1860` is about 8k data. Thus what you see could be explained by a socket write buffer of about 8k which gets very quickly filled up using `seq` and then more slowly emptied when sending the data. Everything which does not fit into the socket buffer gets simply and silently discarded. Similar things happen on the receiver side: if the receiver cannot read fast enough the read buffer will fill up and already transmitted data get discarded instead of being transferred to the application.

socat does not complain if packet got lost (it's UDP). It does not even complain if there is no process receiving any packets at all, i.e. if all data got lost.

Apart from that: it is not 1860 datagrams. It is actually a single datagram with a size of 8192 which gets received in your case. socat does not treat each line as a single message but instead reads and transmits in chunks of 8192 bytes.

Comment: Hmm, ok, the thing is, this is a contrived example which came from a real-world case where I had a UDP sender pumping out individual datagrams indefinitely, but the recvfrom side would just terminate after a random number of received datagrams. It does seem to be the receiver that is giving up. I'll do some more testing and also put wireshark on the case...

EDIT: I just realised that `udp-recvfrom` only receives a single datagram and then socat terminates, unless `fork` is specified, so it's starting to make more sense now. I think the 8192 size with `seq` up to 1860 is a huge clue.

Comment: So revisitiing the original issue - it is actually different from what I described here - using `udp-recvfrom` combined with `fork` randomly terminates with error code 255 after some random number of received datagrams (and in this case each line is a separate datagram, confirmed with wireshark). I'll assume it's just running out of PIDs or something, and use `udp-recv` instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page.  8192 bytes is the block size used by socat, and is also the number of bytes generated by `seq` up to 1860.  So it appears to be stopping after transferring one block.

Comment: `strace -e sendto` shows that socat does not stop sending. And trying with localhost it sends way more then 1860.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  You appear to be seeing different behavior than davidA

Comment: Is there a way to put socat into line-buffered mode so that it sends a separate datagram for each line of input?

FWIW, I created this example because I have a real-world instance of this happening, where the sender is not socat but a C program that is *definitely* sending one datagram per line, yet the recvfrom socat still terminates silently and without error after some number of receipts. The issue with the real-world case is that the number of received messages varies enormously, but with socat-to-socat it's always 1860.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense actually - socat recvfrom only receives a single datagram and then terminates? That might explain why `socat udp-recv` works (does not terminate).

Comment: To clarify, the _sending_ socat does not prematurely terminate, but the receiving one does terminate after receiving a single datagram. The problem was that I had overlooked the fact that socat doesn't line-buffer input into separate datagrams, so it was just printing out the first datagram received (which was ~8192 bytes, "0" to "1860") and then exiting as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Strace shows that seq makes single writes per line when on a terminal (tty,pty). However, on pipe or even on bashs /dev/udp/servername/port it merges lines into "big" writes.

When I try to have seq on a pty controlled by Socat the pty merges a few lines:

```
socat -d -d -d -u EXEC:"strace seq 1 10",pty,rawer UDP-SENDTO:localhost:10000
```

results in something like:

```
write(1, "1\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "2\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "3\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "4\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "5\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "6\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "7\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "8\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "9\n", 2)                      = 2
write(1, "10\n", 3)                     = 3
...
2022/02/15 18:47:01 socat[487411] I transferred 4 bytes from 5 to 6
2022/02/15 18:47:01 socat[487411] I transferred 12 bytes from 5 to 6
2022/02/15 18:47:01 socat[487411] I transferred 2 bytes from 5 to 6
2022/02/15 18:47:01 socat[487411] I transferred 3 bytes from 5 to 6
```